# Is there an easy way to include helper files like bootstrap.min.js inside of my executable for an esp8266 server project?

Tags: c++, bootstrap-4, filesystems, arduino-esp8266

I am using Visual Studio code with Arduino Core to program an esp8266. I have a server running on it, and I have been trying to find a way to package my Bootstrap styling files into the bin that I upload to the esp8266. I have tried esp-spiffs for vs code but there seems to be a bug preventing me from using it. I would also like to avoid the FTP server approach. Finally, the server will not have internet access, so I can not use a CDN link. I plan on rolling out a few deployments of the server, so having everything integrated is the ideal scenario. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: a bug? what bug?

Comment: whenever I try to run a command it shows up in the window at the bottom, but nothing happens. When I try to do something else I get an error saying I have already started another process. I also am not able to cancel or end the request without re-opening the VS code.

Comment: solve that problem, because it is the right way